# A loop that creates unique objects with every iteration. (Based on which iteration)

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I'm using the graphics.py lib and need to create a number of polygons based on how many the user wants (lets say 4).

I just need to know how create a unique name for each of these polygons such as polygon1, polygon2, polygon4, polygon5.

Thanks.

Comment: [You don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html), because you want to [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Just use a `list` of polygon objects, and then you can refer to them as `polygons[2]`, and so on.

Comment: Keep them in a list/dict/set depending on how you need to access them

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, how to create a large number of variables in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129190/in-python-how-to-create-a-large-number-of-variables-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to do this, you could:

```
for i in range(count):
    new_poly = Polygon(whatever)
    new_name = 'polygon{}'.format(i+1)
```

Then you have to store that new name and that new polygon somewhere. Maybe like this:

```
polygons = {}
for i in range(count):
    new_poly = Polygon(whatever)
    new_name = 'polygon{}'.format(i+1)
    polygons[new_name] = new_poly
```

If you were thinking you'd rather just make each name a new variable… that's a bad idea. [You don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html), because you want to [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

And really, there's no need for names here at all. This creates a list of `count` polygons:

```
polygons = [Polygon(whatever) for _ in range(count)]
```

And now, if you need to access them by number, just do this:

```
polygons[2]
```

(although be aware that lists are 0-based, not 1-based).

Or, if you need to access all of them, you've got the whole list, so you don't have to keep writing `(polygon1, polygon2, polygon3, polygon4)` everywhere; just `polygons`.

Comment: Yikes, i neglected to mention that the reason i'm using a loop is so that i can manipulate the attributes of the Polygons (Shifting their coordinates down 1, over 1) as i go about creating them.

Comment: And, so? I think this solution still works fine.. And if that's so, you may don't even need to create the variables dynamically. Just assign them in my loop.

Comment: I'll work on it a bit and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: @MassDiffraction: That's exactly what a list is perfect for: You can loop over it as many times as you need to do things like `for polygon in polygons: polygon.shift(1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it as a list

```
polygon = []
polygon.append(...)
```

And access them as

```
polygon[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bad way:**

You can use `exec`.

```
for i in range(5):
    exec("polygon%d = Polygon(something)"%i)
```

This is pretty safe, since `i` if is only an integer. But using `exec` is a *really* bad practice, since it very vulnerable. User can enter, or accidentally enter, a piece of code and mess up with your memory. So, unless you really **have** to do it, you shouldn't use it.

Also, if you are a fan of global variables, you can use this.

```
globals()["polygon%d"%i] = Polygon(something)
```

But using global vars too often isn't recommended either.

**Nicer way**

Alternatively, you can store it in a list, or a dictionary:

```
for i in range(5):
    lst.append(Polygon(something_else)) #store it in a list
    dict['polygon%d'%i] = Polygon(another_thing) #store it in a dict
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: `exec` is _doubly_ bad. If you really want to dynamically create variables, use `globals()[name] = value` (or `setattr(self, name, value)`, etc.), not `exec`.

Comment: No, there's no reason to even mention `exec` or `globals`. Just say use a list or a dict and leave it at that.

Comment: I don't know that this deserves the downvotes, but it would be a lot better if you reorganized it. This implies that `global` is a "nicer way", when really you should say that the list or dict is the nice way, globals is the very bad way, and exec is the even-worse way…

Comment: Now that's bad. Why the downvote? I also mentioned to use lists and dictionaries, the others are a bonus. Maybe a bad bonus though..

Comment: @abarnert Well, i'll just follow your advice. You're quite a nice teacher.